# Draw .obj file with Three.js without native OBJLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, .obj

I need to draw .obj file, without its loading. For example I have .obj file with follow content

```
v 0.1 0.2 0.3
v 0.2 0.1 0.5
vt 0.5 -1.3
vn 0.7 0.0 0.7
f 1 2 3
```

I read this file, parse content and have its data in a JavaScript object.

```
{
  v: [
    {x:0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
    {x:0.2, 0.1, 0.5}
  ],
  vt: [
    {u: 0.5, v: -1.3}
  ],
  vn: [
    {x: 0.7, 0.0, 0.7}
  ],
  f: [
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Next I need to draw this data with [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js). I read [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/), but can't find any example or description how to do it. Who knows?
Is there any method for that purpose?

Comment: Once you have loaded the file text, you can use parse function of OBJLoader `var myObj = THREE.OBJLoader.parse(text);`

Comment: @2pha I can't use it because this method accept one parameter `text — The textual obj structure to parse`
But I don't have textual obj structure. I have a javascript object

Comment: how are you reading the file?

Comment: why aren't you using OBJLoader? You could look at the [source of OBJLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js) and adapt it for your own needs

Comment: @2pha Let's imagine, I don't have a file. I have a stream or something else and I need to draw this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is, why wont you use `THREE.ObjLoader` ? The reason is not clear to me. There could be so much different test cases for loading obj file. Its better to use `THREE.ObjLoader`.

If you cant use that then 
My preferred way would be to create a `THREE.BufferGeometry`. We are going to create some `THREE.BufferAttribute` from the arrays of your javascript object. One `THREE.BufferAttribute` for each vertex attribute. Also, we gonna set the index buffer. Here is a function to do it -

```
function make_3D_object(js_object) {

    let vertices = new Float32Array(js_object.v);
    let uvs = new Float32Array(js_object.vt);
    let normals = new Float32Array(js_object.vn);

    let indices = new Uint8Array(js_object.f);

    // this is to make it 0 indexed
    for(let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
        indices[i]--;


    let geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geom.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geom.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, 3));
    geom.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
    geom.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));


    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        map: js_object.texture, // assuming you have texture
        color: new THREE.Color().setRGB(1, 1, 1),
        specular: new THREE.Color().setRGB(0, 0,0 )
    } );


    let obj_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);

    return obj_mesh;
}
```

In this code i have assumed you have only a single body, a single material with only a texture. Also this code is not tested.